# Do I need to install python packages as root

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are site-packages in python and can you install/use them if you aren’t root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291922/what-are-site-packages-in-python-and-can-you-install-use-them-if-you-arent-root)

```
sudo apt-get install pip

creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto': Permission denied
```

`pip install boto` modifies the packages under `/usr/local/bin` in a Ubuntu box. Is this the way its supposed to work?

Answer (score 6):

The only package you should install as root is [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) :

```
 #pip install virtualenv
```

Then, you can work in a virtual environment as a normal user. It permits you to experiment without breaking everything in your system:

```
 $virtualenv myproject
 $cd myproject/
 $./bin/pip install boto
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `--user` flag when installing python packages via pip or setup.py. This bypasses the need for root access by installing the package for the current user.

Some packages, such as `virtualenv` need to be installed by root but this is not a common requirement. It's always best to check package docs for installation requirements just in case.

See for more details:

[How to manually install a pypi module without pip/easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install/13271241#13271241)

[How can I install packages in my $HOME folder with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143077/use-pip-and-install-packages-at-my-home-folder)

Comment: You don't have to install virtualenv as root. For example, if you install it with `pip --user`, you simply need to add `~/.local/bin` to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Every python package you install will be installed in root directory, unless you use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). So you will need root access to modify the files in the installation folder. Try using `sudo pip install boto`.