# SymPy installation on 1&1 managed hostig

Tags: javascript, php, python, sympy

I'm an absolute beginner in Python. PHP and JavaScript are no problem. 
For my current project I need SymPy. But unfortunately I don't know how to install SymPy on a 1and1 managed hosting product. Furthermore I don't know how SymPy is called from JavaScript or PHP.

I am very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SSH access to the server you can install it with `pip install sympy` or you can use [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) to install it. SymPy can be used with [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or any python web framework. You can also use cgi to run python scripts.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly that what I'm looking for. Just a hint to the right direction :-) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just one more word. During the Installation an error occure. With the post behind the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680947/do-i-need-to-install-python-packages-as-root) everything works fine